# Why does the Scroll to Text Fragment break my CSS layout?

Tags: javascript, css, search, search-engine, scroll-to-text

When clicking on a result from a Google SERP, sometimes a Scroll to Text Fragment is added to the URL request, e.g. `https://example.com/#:~:text=Lorem%20Ipsum`, and highlights the targeted text in purple. That's pretty neat, but it break my CSS layout.

On one of my divs elsewhere on the page (not the one that gets highlighted), I'm using an absolutely-positioned :before element to add a rounded effect to the top of a 100%-wide div.

[how it normally looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKzD6.png)

The rounded pseudo-element is trimmed off of either side, since it is position: absolute, and not in the page flow. But, when there's a Scroll-to-Text Fragment added, which highlights a paragraph further up the page, for some reason the pseudo element is allowed to push the screen wider and break page layout.

[how it looks if there's a scroll-to-text highlight on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1zWo.png)

Am I forgetting something about how CSS works, or is this a bug?

As a workaround I tried to detect this with JS `window.location.hash` so that I could dynamically remove my pretty rounded effect, but the Scroll to Text Fragment hash is not detected by JS (at least in Chrome). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

### Best Bet:

You could try specifying styling for the **[::target-text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::target-text)** pseudo-element.  If you add your custom styling for target-text, whatever was being added and inherited from the browser's default styling for target-text by your *::before* element should not be added anymore.

### Another option:

You can **turn-off target-text highlighting** altogether for your page, with a document policy directive.  Add this line to the page's response headers:

```
Document-Policy: force-load-at-top
```

If the UA is not modifying your styling at all, it likely won't break your layout.

### Other common misunderstandings:

The normative way to detect if the UA supports target-text is that Document.fragmentDirective exists.

As far as detecting the target-text that is highlighted (your attempt to read target-text from **window.location.hash**).   The [spec specifically prohibits the UA from making the target-text observable by author script](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/#indicating-the-text-match) (javascript).

> The exact appearance and mechanics of the indication are left as
> UA-defined. However, the UA must not use any methods observable by
> author script, such as the Document’s selection, to indicate the text
> match. Doing so could allow attack vectors for content exfiltration.

So you will not be able to detect if or what target-text was linked.